# Hammer.js 2.0 horizontal-only pinch

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

Is there a way to setup pinch event on HTML element using Hammer.js to allow pinch event only on horizontal axis?
I want the vertical axis to be used for standard page scrolling.

When I setup horizontal pan, vertical page scrolling works.
When I setup horizontal pan and pinch, vertical page scrolling stops working. Even one finger scrolling stops working.

```
        var hammerEl = Hammer(element);
        var pan = new Hammer.Pan({
            direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
        });
        var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch({
        });
        hammerEl.add(pan);
        hammerEl.add(pinch);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ph1mpzm1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I added `touchAction: "pan-y"` to Hammer manager.

Docs: http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-action/

Modified test: http://jsfiddle.net/ph1mpzm1/1/

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get pinch to work without blocking the vertical scroll. I'm not sure, but the following might work. Give it a shot. The key is the requireFailure bit. That keeps it from registering a pinch event if it sees you are making a vertical pan gesture.

```
    var hammerEl = Hammer(element);
    var panH = new Hammer.Pan({
        event: "panH",
        direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
    });
    var panV = new Hammer.Pan({
        event: "panV",
        direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL
    });
    var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch({
        enable: true
    });
    hammerEl.add([panH, panV, pinch]);
    pinch.requireFailure(panV);

    hammerEl.on("panH", function(){/*do horizontal pan things*/});
    hammerEl.on("pinch", function(){/*do pinch things*/});
```

Comment: I created jsfiddle with your code and tried from Chrome on Android. Unfortunately does not work (same behavior as my code). http://jsfiddle.net/ouhjpvw0/

Answer (score 0):

we can use hammer event deltaX and deltaY properties for this problem.

```
  const dx = Math.abs(event.deltaX);
    const dy = Math.abs(eevent.deltaY);
    console.log(dx > dy ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical');
```